# How to change the "record external input" in Fraps?

Tags: audio, video-capture, media-player-classic, fraps

I'm using a TV to USB capture thingy called Hauppauge USB-Live2 (http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_usblive2.html) and I'm using Media Player Classic Home Cinema to view my device's output, and finally I'm using Fraps to record the output off of MPC. It all works nicely except I can't get my mic to record, or even show up in the "Record External Input" area of Fraps while my Hauppauge is plugged in.

My question is: How can I select my mic as the "record external input" in fraps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, just had to go into Recording devices by right clicking the volume icon and disable the Hauppauge mic that doesn't seem to do anything.